# Is there a way of using dask jobqueue over ssh

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

Dask jobqueue seems to be a very nice solution for distributing jobs to PBS/Slurm managed clusters. However, if I'm understanding its use correctly, you must create instance of "PBSCluster/SLURMCluster" on head/login node. Then you can on the same node, create a client instance to which you can start submitting jobs.

What I'd like to do is let jobs originate on a remote machine, be sent over SSH to the cluster head node, and then get submitted to dask-jobqueue. I see that dask has support for sending jobs over ssh to a "distributed.deploy.ssh.SSHCluster" but this seems to be designed for immediate execution after ssh, as opposed to taking the further step of putting it in  jobqueue.

To summarize, I'd like a workflow where jobs go `remote --ssh--> cluster-head --slurm/jobqueue--> cluster-node`. Is this possible with existing tools?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently looking into this. My idea is to set-up an SSH tunnel with paramiko and then use Pyro5 to communicate with the cluster object from my local machine.